# discord.py - How to edit embeds? (WITH buttons)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a help command, a custom one.
I'm wondering how you can edit an embed on a button. I know how to edit normal text on a button, but I'm completely clueless about how to do it with embeds. Does anyone know how to do it? Please and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You create an embed called `embed2` and edit the text:

`interaction.edit_original_response(content='',embed=embed2)` if you are using slash command. If not then same deal just with the ctx method to edit a message. The important part is `embed=embed2`.